# How to create class instance and run it method in one string? Python

Tags: python, class, oop

How to create class instance and run it method in one string? Or not create any instance and call this method straight?

For example, i have class Car and method run_car(). How to call run_car() in one string?

```
car = Car()
car.run_car()
```

Comment: Why you have to run_car() in one string? If you change function name of run_car as any other one string, you can do it.

Comment: You can use `Car().run_car()`. But then you can't do anything else with that `Car` instance.

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is exactly what I need. You can write it in answer and I'll mark it as done

Comment: It's already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484000/use-an-object-method-with-the-initializer-same-line

Answer (score 0):

#### Case 1: only need the return value of `run_car()`:

As stated in the comments, this can be done with:

```
result = Car().run_car()
```

#### Case 2: only need the `Car` instance after calling `run_car()`:

Starting with Python 3.8, this can be done using assignment expressions:

```
(car := Car()).run_car()
```

This will create a new `Car` instance, assign it to `car`, and then call `run_car()`. The end result will be the same as:

```
car = Car()
car.run_car()
```

#### Case 3: need both the return value of `run_car()` and the `Car` instance:

This can be done with:

```
result = (car := Car()).run_car()
```

This will create a new `Car` instance, assign it to `car`, and then call `run_car()` and assign its return value to `result`. The end result is the same as:

```
car = Car()
result = car.run_car()
```