# Decorator returning object after running method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I just started learning OOP in Python and came across [interesting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484000/use-an-object-method-with-the-initializer-same-line). In short, it's about running a method in the same line as object is initialised - the proposed solution was to return object after each method which we need to "oneline" that way.

My question is, is there a way to create decorator which will do the same thing?

So instead of defining `colour()` with return:

```py
class Text:

  def __init__(self):
    self.i = 5

  def colour(self, sth):
    self.i = sth
    return self
```

The method would look like that:

```py
  @Returning(self)
  def colour(self, sth):
    self.i = sth
```

This way of doing that is not only a bit more aesthetically pleasing for me, but it easily informs anyone reading the code about method being able to be one-liner, which I find important.
The issue is, though, that trying to come up with my own poor knowledge on decorators, `self` parameter wasn't even recognised when passed into it.

Comment: FYI, the term for this programming style is "fluent programming". It's generally considered unpythonic.

Comment: The argument for the decorator is evaluated when defining the function, it can't refer to variables in the function being decorated. But since `self` is always the first argument, you can write a decorator that always returns the first argument.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much, it worked! Such a shame it's not a main response, I would put it as resolving one.

Comment: It's not really an answer, just pointing you in the right direction. You can post your actual code as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is more pleasing. The new code is no shorter than the old, but now you're obscuring what it does. Why do you think it's important that `colour` is otherwise a one-liner? Nobody *calling* the method will care.

Comment: In case of short example it may not be clear, but [here](https://github.com/Toma400/The_Isle_of_Ansur/blob/Alpha/core/graphics/text_manag.py#L191) you can see more clearly how I find it as "clearer" solution (in this case, it is Callable decorator).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar pointing out that `self` is always first argument passed to function (hence, also decorator), I was able to come up with properly working decorator code:

```py
def Returning(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        return args[0]

    return wrapper_func
```

So the class/run code can look like this:

```py
class Text:

  def __init__(self):
    self.i = 5

  @Returning
  def colour(self, sth):
    self.i = sth

i = Text().colour(25)
```

Thank you!